# ng-directive not working after setting compiled html to div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Before setting the compiled html to `dynamic-html` div, my dynamicHtml is working correctly. As you can see, there's a `onClick` function in *directive*.

But unfortunately, after setting compiled html to div, **`onClick`** is not called anymore.

```
var content = $compile(res)($scope);
$('dynamic-html').html(content);
```

My dynamicHTML directive looks like this:

```
.directive('dynamicHtml', function($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.datePickers = {};

      $scope.onClick = function (variable, $event) {
        var currentTarget = $event.currentTarget;

          $scope.$parent.$parent.highlight(variable, true, currentTarget);
      };
```

I tried to add `transclude` on directive as you can see. But it's not working on  this case.
Can you please guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately you have not shown how the `$scope.onClick` function is called.

Comment: $scope.onClick function is called when users click input fields in dynamic-html div

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Check it out the following code,

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

  .directive("compiled", function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: "AE",
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
          var compiled = $compile("<div><hello-world></hello-world></div>")(scope);
          ele.replaceWith(compiled);
      }
    }
  })

  .directive("helloWorld", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "AE",
      scope: {},
      transculde: true,
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
        scope.sayhello = function(){
          alert("Hello World");
        }
      },
      template: '<button ng-click="sayhello()">Say Hello</button>'
    }
  })
```

**Html**

```
<compiled></compiled>
```

Comment: unfortunately, replaceWith function is not working for me. I've already template file in other folder via pug. what's main solution for my problem